# Calculate the sum of column values in Netsuite Advanced PDF/HTML Templates?

Tags: freemarker, netsuite, bfo

I want to make a subtotal of values corresponding to the same tax code in Netsuite Advanced PDF/HTML. Is it even possible? What are other ways to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible. The templating engine that Netsuite uses under the hood is [Apache FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/), and I would highly recommend looking at the [documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/index.html) there for a full details.

Here is some basic ***untested*** code that you can use to start:

```
<#assign tax1subtotal = 0 >
<#assign tax2subtotal = 0 >
<#assign tax3subtotal = 0 >

<#list record.item as item>

  <#if item.taxcode == [taxcode1]>
     <#assign tax1subtotal = tax1subtotal + item.tax1amt>
  </#if>

  <#if item.taxcode == [taxcode2]>
    <#assign tax2subtotal = tax2subtotal + item.tax1amt>
  </#if>

  <#if item.taxcode == [taxcode3]>
    <#assign tax3subtotal = tax3subtotal + item.tax1amt>
  </#if>

</#list>

Tax Type 1 Subtotal: ${tax1subtotal}<br/>
Tax Type 2 Subtotal: ${tax2subtotal}<br/>
Tax Type 3 Subtotal: ${tax3subtotal}<br/>
```